# Does the Ratchet connectioninterface has other properties than resourceId?

Tags: websocket, properties, ratchet

When you use WebSockets in PHP with Ratchet you can use $conn->resourceId to get the resource ID from the connection.
Does the connection has other properties or is the resource ID the only one?